# Alternative to "A course of pure mathematics" by G.H. Hardy

Tags: analysis, reference-request

I have got the book "The theory of functions" be E.C. Titchmarsh and it states that it is necessary to know the content of Hardys book.
Is there a rather quick way to acquire the knowledge in order to read "The Theory of Functions"?

Comment: Any real analysis textbook should cover the material, and perhaps even a proof based calculus course would cover the majority of it.  However, I don't know if there is a quick way to obtain a textbook's worth of knowledge without reading a textbook/lecture notes.  The question, perhaps, is what can you skip because you already know it.  That isn't something I can answer without knowing your background.

Comment: Why? Do it with calm and passion. "Hurry" and "good" never matched.

Comment: Titchmarsh's book was the text when I took "Complex Variables".  Hardy's book was never mentioned.

Comment: Somewhat echo-ing @herbsteinberg's comment: Titchmarsh's book, and Hardy's, were written at a time when rigorous analysis was not reliably included in undergraduate mathematics curricula, apparently. In contrast, by 2018, at least the rudiments of some systematization (usually Cauchy-Weierstrass epsilon-delta) of proofs-for-analysis are included in most undergrad curricula. So the basic ideas about inequalities and estimates required for Titchmarsh are far more likely to be part of the "environment" nowadays... Summary: you're probably fine.

Comment: @paul garrett My first introduction to epsilon-delta proofs was in 1947, my sophomore year.  I presume that they were being taught before then as well.  The only noticeable change I've noticed in the Stack Exchange is in notation.  The proofs don't seem to be any more rigorous than they were at that time.

Comment: Titchmarsh was Hardy's student and I think he wanted to pay a tribute to Hardy by stating this. That being said Hardy's book is the best introduction to rigorous version of calculus. It starts with Dedekind cuts and has all the $\epsilon-\delta$ stuff plus genuinely difficult and interesting problems.